# Updating records in access from excel and then getting back same records when user wants

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is a very common one. I have researched and found several codes for this but somehow it it is not working for me.

Objective: When the User updates the excel sheet, the data should be saved/updated in access and tomorrow if user wants to view the same the in excel he should be able to see it. The common link between the two dataset is week numnber

Tables I have: 
Table 1: There is one table called schedules. The columns are Associate name, associate ID and There in and out time for the week. There is one box in the upper left connect with week number in it. If User selects week 1, the dates in the column change and the schedule also changes. 
Table 2: It is the leave details table. There I have the employee leaves data i.e. leave start date, leave start time etc. 
Table 3: Calculations. Now here is where all the calculations are happening and the out is being displayed in the schedules sheet when the user clicks on teh refresh button

Question: The part that I am unable to do is:

1. after seeing the schedules displayed in the schedules table, if the user mannually updates the schedule, I want this data to be saved in MS access database. Say, its week 5 running, and at the start of the week user makes that change, I saved the data in access. In the same week, he again opens the data, now I want the user to see the data saved in access and not calculate. SO what I want my code to do is first go to access check if the data is available for the said week or not. If it is not available, come to excel and copy paste a certain data/worksheet.

How do I update and create this check?

Currently M using transferspreadsheet function but that is not solving the problem.

```html
Option Explicit

Sub AccImport()
    Dim acc As New Access.Application
    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\rchoudh\Documents\GEC Project\versions\final\Employee_application_Version_Final_Version.mdb"
    acc.DoCmd.transferspreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:="SavedSchedule", _
            Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:="SavedSchedule$A1:R10000"
    acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acc.Quit
    Set acc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you consider connecting the [Access table to Excel workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-an-Access-database-to-your-workbook-a3d6500c-4bec-40ce-8cdf-fb4edb723525?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)? Also, as an aside why not run everything in Access which better handles: data storage (referential SQL engine instead of flatfile cache memory) and data entry (GUI forms with data type validation instead of rows and columns interface)?

Comment: I tried doing it all in Access but I am a novie. I dnt know much. So have made part of the reports in excel and partly in excel.

Comment: do you mean linking when you say connecting access table to excel workbook?

Comment: Correct. Linking will create an Excel table that mirrors the Access table and that link will be real-time as data changes in Access side will reflect upon refresh or auto-refresh. However this is mainly to present Access data inside Excel for analytic and graphic purposes not to edit. I advise learning about simple Access tables and forms (wizards are available and online tutorials) for your users to better handle the data instead of back and forth copy and paste.